# Turn over-stock Stimpack and Radaway into Caps

Tags: fallout-shelter

As mentioned in title, is there any direct or another way around to do so?
The closest way I got is to equip the excess Stimpack and Radaway to dweller who is traveling to wasteland.

Comment: How does equipping a wasteland explorer with stimpacks turn the stimpacks into money? You're just referring to the money collected during exploration?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way around I could get from other posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, that's the only way to get caps from Stimpacks and Radaways.
If you have too many of them, just remove some workers from the two producing rooms (Science Lab and Medbay) and put them in other rooms.

Independent of how full your stock is, you'll still get caps for collecting more, but equipping them to wastelanders is the intended action.